# Three.js skinning issue from OpenAssetImport-converted model

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, webgl, assimp

I've been trying to understand the maths behind Three.JS's skinning and I've been stuck there for a while.

My use case is loading "any" 3D model that is passed through OpenAssetImport and saved in a custom model format (mostly built for a custom native render, but it's just a representation of assimp's data structures).

In this model format I track:

- Meshes (obviously)
- Nodes (as in the 'assimp' definition of nodes)
- Bones

For each bone, I track:

- The node which it is attached to
- The individual 'bind matrix' as defined by assimp

I'm then struggling to re-construct the skeleton in Three.JS. My attempt is this:

- Generate all the 'nodes' (as in, 'assimp' nodes) as simple `THREE.Object3D`
- Attach the meshes when required
- For each bone

  - Find the node (`THREE.Object3D`) it's attached to
  - Create a new `THREE.Bone`
  - Apply assimp's 'bind matrix' to the ThreeJS bone with `bone.applyMatrix(assimpBone.bindMatrix)`
  - Set the `THREE.Bone` as a child of the `THREE.Object3D`
- Create a `THREE.Skeleton` with the array of `THREE.Bone` objects
- Attach it to the mesh with 'attached' bind mode

However, for some models this works, while for others I have big errors with meshes being de-formed (even if the base mesh is still at least recognizable).

Example mesh loaded with skinning disabled:

[image: no-skinning horse]

Same mesh loaded with skinning enabled:

[image: skinned horse]